Npgsql uneven load balancing during round-robin
I'm seeing strange load balancing behaviour when using Npgsql. I have one primary and three standby servers. As the primary can change (if it goes down and a standby is promoted), I've included all four servers in my connection string, but specified that Standby should be used.
However, the round-robin implementation seems not to balance load evenly. In the following example, where the Primary is host-2, host-3 gets double the amount of connections of the other standby servers. It looks like the round-robin checks the status of host-2 each time it is host-2's turn, and seeing that it is Primary, selects host-3 instead. The round-robin then continues its cycle with host-3 again, meaning that host-3 always gets two connections in succession during the round-robin.
What am I doing wrong here?
public async Task TestConnections(CancellationToken ct = default)
{
    var dataSourceBuilder = new NpgsqlDataSourceBuilder("Host=host-1,host-2,host-3,host-4;Username=***;Password=***;Database=mydb;Load Balance Hosts=True");
    await using var dataSource = dataSourceBuilder.BuildMultiHost()
        .WithTargetSession(TargetSessionAttributes.Standby);

    await using var connection1 = await dataSource.OpenConnectionAsync(ct); // host-1
    await using var connection2 = await dataSource.OpenConnectionAsync(ct); // host-3
    await using var connection3 = await dataSource.OpenConnectionAsync(ct); // host-3
    await using var connection4 = await dataSource.OpenConnectionAsync(ct); // host-4
    await using var connection5 = await dataSource.OpenConnectionAsync(ct); // host-1
    await using var connection6 = await dataSource.OpenConnectionAsync(ct); // host-3
    await using var connection7 = await dataSource.OpenConnectionAsync(ct); // host-3
    await using var connection8 = await dataSource.OpenConnectionAsync(ct); // host-4
    await using var connection9 = await dataSource.OpenConnectionAsync(ct); // host-1
    await using var connection10 = await dataSource.OpenConnectionAsync(ct); // host-3
    await using var connection11 = await dataSource.OpenConnectionAsync(ct); // host-3
    await using var connection12 = await dataSource.OpenConnectionAsync(ct); // host-4
}


It appears that this is a known issue: https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/4181
Similar happens when one instance is down. It is caused by this check which increments poolIndex to use the next available pool from this list, but doesn't increment _roundRobinIndex, meaning that the same pool will be used for the next connection.
There are ideas on the github issue thread on how this could be fixed, but it doesn't seem certain when this will be addressed.
